# Visualization of response variables in hierarchical clustering dendrogram plot

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, dendrogram, vegan

I've like to represent in hierarchical clustering dendrogram plot the response variables "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length"and "Petal.Width" without sucess. I make:

```
#Example with iris data set
library(vegan)
data(iris)
names(iris)
# [1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"  

y <- as.matrix(iris[,-5])[6*(1:25),]   # subsample to make the graphs
rownames(y) <- iris$Species[6*(1:25)]  # pretty

#Calculate distance matrix using Bray
comm.pat.dist <- vegdist(y, method = "bray")

#Create a cluter using hclust 
comm.bc.clust <- hclust(comm.pat.dist, method = "ward.D2")

# Plot cluster 
hpat <- as.dendrogram(comm.bc.clust)
nodePar <- list(lab.cex = 0.6, pch = c(NA, 19), 
                cex = 0.7, col = "blue")
plot(hpat, ylab = "Bray dissimilarity", 
nodePar = nodePar, cex=0.75, edgePar = list(col = 2:3, lwd = 2:1), horiz = TRUE)
#
```

[image: Dedrogarm plot]

And now I don't know what kind of changes in code for represent in the nodes of dendrogram the variables "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length" and "Petal.Width". Any member could help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't represent the variables. You had a dissimilarity matrix for observations (and Bray-Curtis is an inadequate dissimilarity measure), and all information on original variables will be lost in dissimilarities.

Comment: Thanks for explanation Oksanen